# Как решить проблему с черным монитором?

Tags: железо, монитор

Купил монитор, проверил на битые пиксели - все круто.
Принес домой(принес!!!), подключил через dvi-кабель+переходник на thunderbolt-весь экран фиолетовый с зелеными полосками
Отнес обратно, решил не выпендриваться и купил HDMI провод+адаптер на DVI. Подключил - экран черный, но рабочий(я могу с ноутбука переносить на него окна программ, но экран черный и я ничего не вижу на нем)

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Необходимо переключить монитор в режим 'клонирования' рабочего стола. Делается в настройках экрана, в каждой операционной системе - по-своему Уточните так же - виден ли монитор в диагностической утилите с компьютера. Это даст ответ на вопрос в чем проблема. Дополнительно можно попробовать подключить монитор к другому ПК в целях диагностике.

Comment: @Alekcvp Оценил шутку)

Comment: Я так понял, что вы подключали его к другому компьютеру по VGA и он работал? Тогда есть два варианта:а) почитать инструкцию на монитор и найти как переключать входы (некоторые мониторы не умеют в автомат, хотя я таких видел единицы), б) подключить другой, заведомо рабочий по DVI, монитор к MACу и убедиться что это не проблема с видеокартой.

Comment: к сожалению, железо - оффтопик на ruSO